# Reversing integer but getting `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that reverses the integer which starts with the negative sign. For example, if the number is `-123`, the output should be `-321`. But I'm getting:

`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4`

in line:

```
result += myString.charAt(i) + "";
```

What is wrong with the logic of the code?

```
public class ReverseInteger {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int x = -123;
        String myString = Integer.toString(x);
        String result = "";

        if(myString.charAt(0) == '-'){
            char sign = myString.charAt(0);
            for(int i = myString.length(); i > 1; i--){
                result += myString.charAt(i) + "";
            }
            result = sign + "" + result;
        }

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think _StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4_ means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing a `String` or array in java is *zero based*. This means that index `0` is the first character in the string, and `mystring.length() - 1` is the last character in the string. `mystring.length()` is *past the end* of the string.

Since you're accessing the array at index `mystring.length()` you're exceeding the bounds of the array, hence the exception.

You want to begin your loop at index `mystring.length() - 1`. Furthermore you'll want to continue down to index `1`, instead of excluding that index as in your loop.

Like so:

```
for (int i = myString.length() - 1; i > 0; i--)
```

Comment: it should be `i >= 0` but would still accept the answer in 10 mins :), @pb2q

Comment: @John you can use `i > 0` _or_ `i >= 1`, but _not_ `i >= 0`, since you're handling index 0 specially, when you look for the sign. So you don't want to  touch index 0 in your loop.

Comment: Oh, sorry and nevermind! I did `i >= 1`, and made a mistake here by saying that i >= 0. Sorry again and thanks! @pb2q

Comment: hey no problem @John. it's a simple concept, but can take a surprisingly long time before it's natural

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using

```
for(int i = myString.length(); i > 1; i--){
    result += myString.charAt(i) + "";
}
```

`String.length()` returns a length from 1 to X. 0 is for empty strings.

you need to add -1

```
for(int i = myString.length() - 1; i > 0; i--){
   result += myString.charAt(i) + "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below line seems to be the issue

```
result += myString.charAt(i) + "";
```

Change it to:

```
result += myString.charAt(i-1) + "";
```